# In a details element, how to prevent the onclick event on clicking the content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to apply an onClick event on a `details` tag. However, I found that after applying the event, clicking the elements apart from `details` and `summary` also triggers the event.

My question is: how can I make the onClick event only triggered on clicking the `details` and `summary` tags, and not triggered on any other elements?

Here is an example: clicking on `Panel content` triggers the console log. I only want the function to be triggered on clicking `Panel title`.

Panel.js

```
import React from "react";
const Panel = ({ toggleDetails, id }) => {
  return (
    <details onClick={() => toggleDetails(id)}>
      <summary>Panel title</summary>
      <div>Panel content</div>
    </details>
  );
};
export default Panel;
```

App.js

```
let details = [];
export default function App() {
  const id = "panel";
  const toggleDetails = (name) => {
    if (details.includes(name)) {
      details = details.filter((item) => item !== name);
      console.log(details, "in if");
    } else {
      details = [...details, name];
      console.log(details, "in else");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Panel toggleDetails={toggleDetails} id={id} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-dan-sezj6?

Comment: you can add onclick event to summary and div and remove details one, if you dont want to hard code it use javascript to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can add the event handler to the `summary` element, not to `details` element, and for other cases, you can use [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) if you don't want the child to trigger the parent's event